# how to get datetime from entity (remote.get_states(api)]

Tags: python, python-3.x, entity, state

im using python to save the values of sensors in csv file.
I dont know how can i get the timesstamp from intity.
This is the entity:

```
<state sensor.aeotec_zw074_multisensor_gen5_luminance=1000.0; value_id=72057594076479538, value_instance=1, node_id=2, friendly_name=Aeotec ZW074 MultiSensor Gen5 Luminance, value_index=3, unit_of_measurement=lux, new_entity_id=sensor.aeotec_zw074_multisensor_gen5_luminance, old_entity_id=sensor.aeotec_zw074_multisensor_gen5_luminance_2_3 @ 2017-10-17T12:57:14.532186+00:00>
```

this the script yhat iam using and i want to expand time as well:

```
aeotec_zw074_multisensor_gen5_temperature = remote.get_state(api, ‘sensor.aeotec_zw074_multisensor_gen5_temperature’)
print(’{} is {} {}.’.format(aeotec_zw074_multisensor_gen5_temperature.name,
aeotec_zw074_multisensor_gen5_temperature.state,
aeotec_zw074_multisensor_gen5_temperature.attributes[‘unit_of_measurement’]
)
```

)

Could someone help me how to get time @ 2017-10-17T12:57:14.532186+00:00 from entity  please?

Comment: What is the "entity"?  It's not a .csv file, because it doesn't have comma-separated values.  It looks like malformed XML.  What function returns that?

Comment: entity is like a list of dictionories contains all data about each sensor.
it's already programmed in home assistant plateform.

Comment: What format is it, specifically?  I'm confused because you posted neither a list nor a dictionary.  Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: iam not sure if i can answer your question. I use "remote.API" Module to get access of a database (sqlite) 
could you please check this link https://home-assistant.io/developers/python_api/

Comment: I can post an example of entity if you are interessting to know how it looks like

Comment: Only if you feel like it would be helpful for posterity - it looks like you figured this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import homeassistant.remote as remote
api = remote.API('127.0.0.1', 'YOUR_PASSWORD')
data = remote.get_state(api, 'sensor.random_sensor')
print(data.last_changed)
```